# How to delete text when a user clicks a JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield, focuslistener

In my program, the user writes something in a `JTextField` then clicks a 'generate' button, which triggers the characters in the `JTextField` to be drawn to a `JPanel`.

I would then like to clear all the text in the `JTextField` when the user clicks the `JTextField` again. I tried to achieve this by adding a `FocusListener` and an `ActionListener` to the `JTextField`, however my attempts did not work. Moreover, my implementation of the `FocusListener` gave an `Unreachable Statement` compiler error.

Is this possible to do in Java and if so how can I do this?

The code below is my `ActionListener` implementation.

```
dfaText = new JTextField(6);
dfaText.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        generateLabel.setText("NOOOOO!!!");
        dfaText.setText("");

        isDfaDrawn = false;
        canDraw = false;
        repaint();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of the code?

Comment: "when the user clicks it" click on what ?? button???

Comment: No, when user clicks the textfield.

Comment: What about when the user TABS to the text field? Don't assume a user uses a mouse. A FocusListener should be used instead of the MouseListener.

Comment: When I use FocusListener, it gives unreachable statement (for example) for generateLabel, dfaText, isDrawn... etc. Do you have any idea about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a mouse listener:

```
field.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
  @Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    field.setText("");
  }
});
```

Bear in mind this could get frustrating if the user legitimately clicks elsewhere and returns to the field. You may wish to maintain some state, e.g. only clear the field if the button has been clicked in the interim.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
textField.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        textField.setText("");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just an addition to others' code.

```
public void textfieldMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    uname_tf.setText(null);
} //This will set the JTextfield blank on mouse click//      

public void textfieldFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                   
    uname_tf.setText("Username");
} //This will bring back the default text when not in focus//
```

Hope it helps, Cheers!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want it just one Click on it to delete the text  you can do  like this :

```
textField.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                textFieldMousePressed(evt);
            }
        });
 private void textFieldMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
          textField.setText("");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 1 line to you buttonMethod e.g:

```
txtfield.clear();
```

or set your txtfield to an empty string